# bash. Выборочное удаление

Tags: linux, bash

Команда:

`findimagedupes -R -t 99 *.jpg`

Выводит найденные файлы в виде:

```
1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg
7.jpg 9.jpg
15.jpg 25.jpg 35.jpg
```

Как удалить все файлы, кроме первого, в каждой строке?

Answer (score 2):

Если верить [man](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/manpage.html)'у, то ИМХО лучше будет воспользоваться встроенными возможностями утилиты, подсунув ей скрипт просмотра через `-i`:

```
findimagedupes -t 99 *.jpg -i 'VIEW() {shift; rm "$@"}'
```

У других способов вероятно будут проблемы с необычными именами файлов.